# Android - Memory Cost - Firebase Realtime Database x Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, firebase, memory, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

Debugging Firebase Realtime Database method `ValueEventListener.onDataChange`, `DataSnapshot` loads all data from the Cloud.

Thinking in low memory cost, what is the best solution to work with the large amount of data ( in device perspective )?

Im looking to implement both, using Firebase Realtime Database to do a daily update to storage local data with the Room Database. For this way, only necessary data is loaded to device's memory, based on user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thinking in low memory cost, what is the best solution to work with the large amount of data ( in device perspective )?

The best solution is to use limitations. This the official documentation regarding [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) in Firebase real-time database. As you can see, there are a few methods that can help you achieve this.

If you will attempt to load enormous amount of data you can encounter an error that sounds like this:

```
OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 28701016 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
```

In such cases, you should create an index on the desired property. Without it, the server can't do the ordering/filtering for you, and it will be done in the client. That means the client has to read all data and keep it in memory, explaining the huge memory usage.

The solution is quite simple. Using [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) you should define an index on your `desired` property. It can be as simple as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "codes": {
      ".indexOn": "yourProperty"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is great, I was not aware of this Firebase index feature. But I think I need to change my JSON data model to make indexes viable.
Currently my data model follows this pattern: https://pastebin.com/zv6Jz679

To improve the usability of Firebase Query, I think the database model must be like: https://pastebin.com/Sv7cdvuY

Comment: There is no perfect or one solution for structuring a Firebase database. The best solution, is the solution that fits your needs and makes your job easier. If that schema it best for you, then go ahead and use it. To add an index is a common practice when it comes to large amount of data in FIrebase.